# Чёрный вывод изображения с камеры. OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, камера, компьютерное-зрение, web-камера

Камера работает, во всех приложениях показывает, но в окне OpenCV я получаю чёрное изображение с какими-то артефактами.
Скрипт самый стандартный:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    if cv2.waitKey(13) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        # cv2.imwrite('capture.png', frame)
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Вывод:
[image: OpenCV cam output]

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html

Answer (score 0):

1. вы уверены, что камера доступна по чтению?

   ```py
   cap = cv.VideoCapture(0) 
     if not cap.isOpened():
         print("Cannot open camera")
         exit()
   ```
2. почему стоит 1, а не 0? у вас 2 веб-камеры?
3. вы уверены. что прочитали кадр с камеры

   ```py
   while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # if frame is read correctly ret is True
        if not ret:
            print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
            break
   ```

Comment: 1. Ошибки нет, камера открывается (вроде как)
2. 1 стоит т.к. 0 используется для встроенной камеры, а 1 и далее - для внешних (если поставить 0, то вообще ничего не выводится и не показывается)
3. Ошибок нет

Comment: И ещё, светодиод камеры во время работы программы не горит (т.е. камера никакого изображения не отдаёт)

Comment: OpenCV не предназначен для работы с камерами, используйте SDK камеры

Comment: ок, давайте подробности, камера подключена через usb?  у вас windows или linux?

Comment: Pavel Gridin, а вот это как?  import cv;
video = cv.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.1.2:8080/out.h264")